# Vacation planning with automated coordination / priorities?

Tags: scheduling

I got the unthankful job of coordinating 50 peoples vacation wishes.

I find a lot off apps that let me receive each request and approve it quickly, but I can't seem to find anything that asks the employee for different choices and lets me assign priorities to people.

There should be parameters I can set like:
how many people can be on holiday at the same time,
which groups of people can be away at the same time,
which peoples 1st, 2nd or 3rd choice should be taken into account and when.

Sounds a bit like timetable creating/ scheduling, but shouldnt that be part of vacetion planning?

Cheers

Comment: You could take a look at PollUnit. I'm only adding this as a comment, because as a creator you can't prioritize specific people - at least not automatically (if I have understood this correctly?). But you can do all sorts of other polls besides simple scheduling, like prioritizations with dot-voting, star rating, finding consensus, up to automatic task distribution. You can find more here: https://pollunit.com/en/voting

Comment: yes, i thought about polling and its a decent alternative, if you get the raw data of the vacation requests out of it. at least i could more or less easily visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need a scheduler or rota/roster builder, with appropriate constraints entered, to do this. A couple of examples are:

- [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)
- [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/)

But if you want employees to book in a calendar with some simple constraints, then you modify yourself manaully, you can try [BookedScheduler](https://github.com/effgarces/BookedScheduler) with the resource being "Vacation"

Comment: optaplanner looks like the right tool. now i just need someone to program me one sexy app out of it^^

Comment: Ask the OptPlanner team in case there is one out there.... You can also pay them to do it.